How do I configure X-RateLimit-Limit response headers when using .NET's rate limiting feature?
I'm using the Rate Limit feature introduced in .NET 7.
How can I set the X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, and X-RateLimit-Reset response headers appropriately when the rate limit is exceeded?
I'm looking for a reasonably generic solution that can be implemented across many endpoints with different policies.
